# a simple question about casting integers in c++

Tags: c++

i have the following very simple code -

```
int x=15000
int z=0.7*x
cout<<"z = "<<z<<endl;
```

i get the output

```
z=10499
```

but if i change it to

```
int z=0.7*15000
cout<<"z = "<<z<<endl;
```

outputs

```
z=10500
```

i understand it has something to do with z casting the result to int
but why is it different in both cases ?

thanks,

EDIT -
i'm using ubuntu's 10.10 GCC build

Comment: I have 10500 (gcc 4.2)... what compiler are you using? is it exactly the code you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

int z=0.7*x;

The double-precision value 0.7 is not exactly representable as a floating-point number; its hex representation is 3fe6666666666666 on most machines, which is less than the true value 3fe6666666666666... So the double-precision result of 0.7*x is less than its true value, and is rounded down. This is correct behaviour.

int z=0.7*15000;

The compiler, on the other hand, is clever enough to see that 0.7 * 15000 is representable exactly as 7 * 1500 = 10500. So it uses the correct result, instead of the result that would be obtained by compiling the expression and executing it.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it's because of compiler, that simplifies arithmetical expressions at the compile time.

The first expression was computed using FPU (with finite precision), and the second one: by preprocessor (with "infinite" precision). Try running the program in release mode (or with `-O2`), the results should be the same for both expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I think ruslik has the correct answer to your question.

I would just add: Always keep your calculations in either float or double until the very last moment. That way you don't lose precision.

Try changing your code to this:

```
double z = 0.7 * 15000.0;
cout<<"z = "<<z<<endl; // Will need to include some formatting
```

or

```
int z = (int) (0.7 * 15000.0);
cout<<"z = "<<z<<endl;
```

Comment: Both these suggestions are no-ops, and do nothing to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is that 0.7*x gives a different result to 0.7*15000. See my answer below/above.

Comment: I think this is good advice. If you need double precision then keep your variables in doubles. Use rounding as the last step, if necessary.